# ImageView: scale too large images down, don't scale too small images up

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image

I guess the title already says what I want to do:

I have an `ImageView`, when the image to display has been loaded from the web (with [UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)) I want to

a. have the image scaled down to fit into the `ImageView` if the image is larger than the `ImageView`

b. not scale the image up but rather display in it's original size when the Image is smaller than the `ImageView`

Bot are no problem with

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

for a. and

```
android:scaleType="center"
```

for b.

Is there any possibility to combine the two? 
Will my only option be to 'manually' compare the size of the ImageView and the size of the loaded BitMap with each other and set the `scaleType` accordingly?

EDIT: This is my UIL config:

```
public static final DisplayImageOptions uiloptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
        .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
        .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
        .cacheInMemory(true)
        .cacheOnDisk(true)
        .build();

imageLoaderConfiguration = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this)
        .threadPoolSize(2)
        .defaultDisplayImageOptions(Values.uiloptions).build();
```

Comment: Try use image loading library with various option achieved ur requirement : http://square.github.io/picasso/ and https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader.

Comment: i guess UIL handles this on basis of size of imageview you dont have to do anything extra

Comment: @apk Currently it doesn't it scales my small images up. Added my UIL config.

Comment: @Ascorbin share your imageview xml dont add wrap_content specify width and height you want it will work

Comment: @apk The imageView is just a standard ImageView with width  = match_parent and the height match_parent.

Comment: @Ascorbin specify height and width in dp it will work and also will improve performence

Comment: @apk that won't really work because I want the ImageView to take all available space and have no border.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this attribute:

```
android:scaleType="centerInside"
```

[Here is a link](http://etcodehome.blogspot.com/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html)